# How to display if a Google Form is open or closed?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many Google Forms live (e.g. over 50) that are scheduled to close once a certain number of responses have been received. I would like to create a quick dashboard in Sheets that shows me if a form is open or closed. This will save me from opening each individual form and I can then see everything on one page

I have googled this but cannot find an answer so am not sure it is even possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What do `open` and `close` of `How to display if a Google Form is open or closed?` mean? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method of Google Forms services called `isAcceptingResponses()`. With this method you can see if a Google form is accepting answers or not.

You can read more information about this method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#isAcceptingResponses())

Here is a sample on how to use it, if you already have the ID of the form:

```
function formStatus() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  //Manually add the ID of the form. 
  let form = FormApp.openById('form_ID');
  let form_status = form.isAcceptingResponses();

  //this will add the ID of the form and the status in the google Sheet
  sheet.appendRow(['form_ID', form_status])
}
```

It will look something like this:

[image: example]

If you do not have the IDs of the Google Forms, you can use a function like this one to list the forms in Google Drive. With this code you can list all the Google Forms inside of your Drive and return the ID.

```
function search_forms(){
  let form_list = DriveApp.searchFiles('mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.form"');
  
  while (form_list.hasNext()) {
    let form_id = form_list.next().getId();
    Logger.log(form_id)
  }
}
```

You can later iterate the IDs using the same methods on the other code, like this.

```
function search_forms(){
  let form_list = DriveApp.searchFiles('mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.form"');
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  while (form_list.hasNext()) {

    //gets the file IDs in Google Drive
    let form_id = form_list.next().getId();
    let form = FormApp.openById(form_id);

    // review if the form is accepting answers or not
    let form_status = form.isAcceptingResponses();

    //this will add the ID of the form and the status in the google Sheet
    sheet.appendRow([form_id, form_status])
    
  }
}
```

And it will look like this:

[image: sample2]

### Update:

If you have a list of IDs already at hand, you can added them to a Google Sheet like this:

[image: Arrange data]

After that, you can use this code that will get all the IDs from the Google Sheet, and will review the status of the Form, you can later place it in the next column.

```
function formStatus() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  //gets the IDs from the column A on Google sheets
  let form_list = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();

  //start a counter so we can place the status in the correct row
  // I made it start in row 2 since is the way I configure my data
  let count = 2

  //Filter and remove all the empty values
  form_list = form_list.filter((element) => element !== '');

  form_list.forEach(function form_ID(form_id) {
    
    let form = FormApp.openById(form_id);
        // review if the form is accepting answers or not
    let form_status = form.isAcceptingResponses();

    //this will add the ID of the form and the status in the Google Sheet
    // the value will be added in column B
    sheet.getRange(count,2).setValue(form_status)
    count +=1
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It is really great and nearly does exactly what I want it to do. With the first example, if I have all the Form ID's, how can i add all of them into the code. The second option you provide lists forms that I don't need. Also, if I set up a timer trigger, will it be dynamic (e.g update the status automatically)?

Comment: @ColinSmith, I added an update in the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect and does exactly what I need. Thank you!